# How to show draw effects in legend in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer, legend, printing

I have edited the features on my map using the draw effects tool (colourize, glow etc). However, in Print Composer, the legend shows these feature symbols in their original form. How can I get them to match my edited symbols?

I am using QGIS 2.14.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2.16.1.

Answer (score 4):

This feature will be available starting with QGIS 3.0.

You can see the preview here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3763